# How can I upload Image Large Size

Tags: php, laravel

I alreay change

memory_limit => -1 => -1

post_max_size => 25M => 25M

and when I try to dd($request->img);

if I used 2mb It's work but if I use 6mb It return this when I try to dd

```
UploadedFile {#434 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "test.JPG"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 07:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 07:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 07:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

**UPDATE**

here is my . html

```
<form action="{{ route($route.'store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="img" class="dropify" data-height="300" >
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: no It just return null value when I try to dd($request->image)

Comment: What webserver are you using? Did you set the max upload size in your webserver?

Comment: Please add the html code and the php to try to solve this issue and if you put your apache.conf better.

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04 @Jerodev

Comment: alerdy update my html @PacoGómezCapón

Comment: @TryHardz data-height is for what?

Comment: It's css add height into input @PacoGómezCapón

Answer (score 0):

edit your `php.ini` file and set:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 70M
post_max_size = 100M
```

and restart apache.

Comment: still not working .

Comment: @TryHardz make sure you restart your apache.

Comment: yes I alredy  sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: @TryHardz maybe your problem came from the controller where you also have an option to set the max size.

Comment: no I didnt set anything in my controller  didnt make any validate or rules

Comment: is that weird  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream" ?

Comment: @TryHardz no. `application/octet-stream` is defined as "arbitrary binary data" in RFC 2046, and there's a definite overlap here of it being appropriate for entities whose sole intended purpose is to be saved to disk

Comment: cant find any error It's just return null value :( don't know why It can't get data from $request->image

Comment: can you able to post on your content your `php.ini` files?

Comment: no I think I cant post I too much data , but I've recheck memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 70M
post_max_size = 100M

Comment: That's kinda weird dude.

Comment: yes  !! I've no Idea ...